# What is considered success when executing SQL query?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a quick question, since I am not sure what is considered success when using execute.

```
$test_id=5;
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE test_db SET request_time=now() WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$test_id);
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

I know that execute returns 1 on success and 0 on failure.
But what exactly is failure? Is it a failure if the query went through, but updated 0 rows?

I would test this myself, but I don't have an environment that I can use.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's ridiculously simple: success is when there is **no error**. And a failure is when your query is not executed at all because of error. So you don't really need the $result variable.

Comment: And here is your [test environment](https://phpize.online/)

Comment: Thanks for explaining it! But isn't the $result variable is useful if you want to do something when a query failed. For example log it.

Comment: Not at all. That's outdated and obsoleted method. In modern PHP the error will reveal itself and PHP will log it. All without your intervention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Success is when there is no error.

And a failure is when your query is not executed at all because of error. So you don't really need the $result variable, because the error will reveal itself.

It means you don't need to write any code to test for success:

- in case of success your code will just run further
- in case of failure the error will be raised and it will be handled elsewhere

See my article on [PHP error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) for the in-depth explanation